# Lag in Stata generates only missing

Tags: stata

I have a trouble using L1 command in Stata 14 to create lag variables.
The resulted Lag variable is 100% missing values!

> gen d = L1.equity

tnanks in advance

Comment: How is your data `tsset`?

Comment: does your time variable have gaps? Does your equity variable contain missing values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is hardly enough information given in the question to know for certain, but as @Dimitriy V. Masterov suggested by questioning how your data is `tsset`, you likely have an issue there.

As a quick example, imagine a panel with two countries, country 1 and country 3, with gdp by country measured over five years:

```
clear
input float(id year gdp)
1 1 5
1 2 2
1 3 7
1 4 9
1 5 6
3 1 3
3 2 4
3 3 5
3 4 3
3 5 4
end
```

Now, if you improperly `tsset` this data, you can easily generate the missing values you describe:

```
tsset year id
gen lag_gdp = L1.gdp
```

And notice now how you have 10 missing values generated. In this example, it happens because the panel and time variables are out of order and the (incorrectly specified) time variable has gaps (period 1 and period 3, but no period 2).

Something else I have witnessed is someone trying to `tsset` by their time variable *and* their analysis variable, which is also incorrect:

```
clear
input float(year gdp)
1 5
2 3
3 2
4 4
5 7
end

tsset year gdp
gen d = L1.gdp
```

I suspect you are having a similar issue.

Without knowing what your data looks like or how it is `tsset` there is no possible way to diagnose this, but it is very likely an issue with how the data is `tsset`.